# Highlighting the current line in vim via the sign ('gutter') column

Tags: vim, highlighting

When using vim in a terminal, `set cursorline` results in the current line being underlined. I find this visually clunky and would prefer to only change the background (or foreground) color of the *current line number* in the sign (or 'gutter') column.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `~/.vimrc` you can use

```
:set number
:set cursorline
:hi cursorline cterm=none
:hi cursorlinenr ctermfg=red
```

This stops the cursor line being drawn as a line in a colour terminal, but the line number at
the cursor changes colour.  I have vim 7.4. `cursorlinenr` is not in 7.3.